# Passing va_list to multi functions without invoke va_arg

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I need to implement this code as follows:

```
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct desc{
    void (*function)(void*)  //Function address
    int no_arg;              // Number of arguments
    va_list arg;             //arguments list
} desc;

desc* creater(void(*func)(), int no_arg1,...){
      desc *new_desc;
      va_list arg1;
      new_desc = (desc*)malloc(sizeof(struct desc));
      new_desc->function = func;
      new_desc->no_arg = no_arg1;
      va_start(arg1 , no_arg1);
      va_copy(new_desc->arg,arg1);
      va_end(arg1);
}

void start(void(*func)(), va_list varg){
      func(&varg);
}

void strat_work(struct desc *desc1){
      start( desc1->function,desc1->arg);
}

int test_func(int x, int y){
      printf(" The value is =",x + y);
}

int main(void){
          desc *desc2;
          desc = creater(test_func, 2, 1, 3);

          start_work(&desc);
          return 0;
}
```

**Could anyone shed light on this implementation?** I can see an answer fuzzily also it accepted just one argument.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 0):

Once `creator()` has returned, the `va_list` variable and all variable arguments it points to are invalid. You have to extract those arguments before `creator()` returns. I'm afraid you have to use `va_arg()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to pass all arguments  as parameter to enable another function, therefore, I used va_list. Do you have any other way to implement this producer.

Comment: Add an `int*` pointer in `desc`. In `creator()` allocate enough memory for `no_arg` of `int` parameters, extract them with `va_arg()`, store them.

Comment: How could I extract them with    va_arg() and I don't know the types of the arguments?

Comment: You'll have to know them one way or another. How does `printf()` do it? That's one way.